# How to change items position in small devices in tailwindcss

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

This is my code. But on mobile devices the Connect button is on the left as shown in the image below:
[image: connect button on left].

I want to move connect button to the right on mobile devices just before the discod button.

This is my code:

```
export function SiteHeader() {
  return (
    <header className="fixed top-0 z-50 w-full border-b border-border/40 bg-background/95 backdrop-blur supports-[backdrop-filter]:bg-background/60">
      <div className="container flex h-14 max-w-screen-2xl items-center">
        <MainNav />
        <MobileNav />
        <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-between space-x-2 md:justify-end">
          <div className="w-full flex-1 md:w-auto md:flex-none">
            <Button>Connect</Button>
          </div>
          <nav className="flex items-center">
            <Link
              href=""
              target="_blank"
              rel="noreferrer"
            >
              <div
                className={cn(
                  buttonVariants({
                    variant: "ghost",
                  }),
                  "w-9 px-0"
                )}
              >
                <Icons.discord className="h-4 w-4" />
                <span className="sr-only">Discord</span>
              </div>
            </Link>
            <Link
              href=""
              target="_blank"
              rel="noreferrer"
            >
              <div
                className={cn(
                  buttonVariants({
                    variant: "ghost",
                  }),
                  "w-9 px-0"
                )}
              >
                <Icons.twitter className="h-3 w-3 fill-current" />
                <span className="sr-only">Twitter</span>
              </div>
            </Link>
            <ModeToggle />
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```html
<div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-between space-x-2 md:justify-end">
  <div className="w-full flex-1 md:w-auto md:flex-none">
```

to

```html
<div className="flex flex-1 items-center space-x-2 justify-end">
  <div className="w-auto flex-none">
```

We transpose the `md:` classes to have no variants. This will mean they will apply for all viewports i.e. now including "mobile". At the same time, we remove conflicting classes.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.0"></script>

<header class="fixed top-0 z-50 w-full border-b border-border/40 bg-background/95 backdrop-blur supports-[backdrop-filter]:bg-background/60">
  <div class="container flex h-14 max-w-screen-2xl items-center">
    <MainNav>MainNav</MainNav>
    <MobileNav>MobileNav</MobileNav>
    <div class="flex flex-1 items-center space-x-2 justify-end">
      <div class="w-auto flex-none">
        <Button>Connect</Button>
      </div>
      <nav class="flex items-center">
        <Link
          href=""
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer"
        >
          <div
            class="w-9 px-0"
          >
            <Icons.discord class="h-4 w-4">Icons.discord</Icons.discord>
            <span class="sr-only">Discord</span>
          </div>
        </Link>
        <Link
          href=""
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer"
        >
          <div
            class="w-9 px-0">
            <Icons.twitter class="h-3 w-3 fill-current">Icons.twitter</Icons.twitter>
            <span class="sr-only">Twitter</span>
          </div>
        </Link>
        <ModeToggle>ModeToggle</ModeToggle>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```